# My Json Object _id has no ObjectId Instead it has timestamp, machineIdentifier, processIdentifier, counter etc

Tags: java, jackson, apache-camel, jackson-databind

I have written a camel route which is fetching data from mongoDb. The problem is the object's I am getting is query response has different format of `_id` field.

**Existing format**

```
"_id": {
        "timestamp": 1521810820,
        "machineIdentifier": 13135022,
        "processIdentifier": 6716,
        "counter": 11018640,
        "time": 1521810820000,
        "date": 1521810820000,
        "timeSecond": 1521810820
    }
```

**Desired format**

```
"_id" : "5ab4fd84c86cae1a3ca82190"
```

**Camel Route**

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8181/mongoSelect")
        .to(QUERY_MONGO_DB)
        .marshal(new JacksonDataFormat())
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
            }
        })
        .to("direct:redis");
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Camel and MongoDG. But your "desired format" is _not_ valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, This format is copied from mongoDB, the object format is `"_id": "5ab4fd84c86cae1a3ca82190"`, I placed this format just to explain what exacty that thing is.

Comment: What is your question? I can't find it. And how did you get the "Desired format"?